# Install pandas for python3.7 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm having issues with installation pandas under python3.7 on Ubuntu. I created virtual environment with python3.7, but `pip install pandas` takes forever to install and eventually stops. I managed to install pandas for python3.6 with simple `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`, but can't find proper way to install it for python3.7

Comment: just curious, should it be `pip3 install pandas`? You can also download the source code and do `pip3 install -e /path/to/pandas/source/`.

Comment: It's pip, since I'm in virtual environment

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

or

```
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```